# F# - Merge modules?

Tags: entity-framework, f#, ef-code-first

I'm at the moment working on a Entity Framework Code First Wrapper for F#, and I've been wondering whether I should merge all my modules into just one.

Take a look at this:

```
module ManyNavProperty =
    let withMany (cfg:ManyNavPropertyInfo<'a,'b>) = cfg.WithMany()
    let withSeq expr (cfg:ManyNavPropertyInfo<'a,'b>) = cfg.WithSeq expr
    let withList expr (cfg:ManyNavPropertyInfo<'a,'b>) = cfg.WithList expr
    let withArray expr (cfg:ManyNavPropertyInfo<'a,'b>) = cfg.WithArray expr
    let withOptional (cfg:ManyNavPropertyInfo<'a,'b>) = cfg.WithOptional()
    let withOptionalProperty expr (cfg:ManyNavPropertyInfo<'a,'b>) = cfg.WithOptional expr
    let withRequired (cfg:ManyNavPropertyInfo<'a,'b>) = cfg.WithRequired()
    let withRequiredProperty expr (cfg:ManyNavPropertyInfo<'a,'b>) = cfg.WithRequiredProperty expr

module DependentNavProperty =
    let hasForeignKey expr (cfg:DependentNavPropertyInfo<'a>) = cfg.HasForeignKey expr

module CascadableNavProperty =
    let willCascadeOnDelete b (cfg:CascadableNavPropertyInfo) = cfg.WillCascadeOnDelete b

module EF =
    let entity<'a when 'a : not struct> (cfg:DbModelBuilder) = EntityInfo<'a>(cfg.Entity<'a>())
    let hasKey expr (cfg:EntityInfo<'a>) = cfg.HasKey expr
    let hasSeq expr (cfg:EntityInfo<'a>) = cfg.HasSeq expr
    let hasList expr (cfg:EntityInfo<'a>) = cfg.HasList expr 
    let hasArray expr (cfg:EntityInfo<'a>) = cfg.HasArray expr
    let hasOptional expr (cfg:EntityInfo<'a>) = cfg.HasOptional expr
    let hasRequired expr (cfg:EntityInfo<'a>) = cfg.HasRequried expr
    let toTable s (cfg:EntityInfo<'a>) = cfg.ToTable s
```

that would require me to call the code like:

```
override x.OnModelCreating (mb:DbModelBuilder) =
    let finished = ignore
    let entity = EF.entity<Author> mb

    entity
    |> EF.hasSeq <@ fun z -> z.Books @>
        |> ManyNavProperty.withRequiredProperty <@ fun z -> z.Author @>
            |> DependentNavProperty.hasForeignKey <@ fun z -> z.AuthorId @>
                |> CascadableNavProperty.willCascadeOnDelete true
    |> finished
```

Is the use of so many modules confusing for the user? - Should I place them all into one module, or will that destroy the overview for the user?

An example where all functions are placed in same Module:

```
override x.OnModelCreating (mb:DbModelBuilder) =
    let finished = ignore
    let entity = EF.entity<Author> mb

    entity
    |> EF.hasSeq <@ fun z -> z.Books @>
        |> EF.withRequiredProperty <@ fun z -> z.Author @>
            |> EF.hasForeignKey <@ fun z -> z.AuthorId @>
                |> EF.willCascadeOnDelete true
    |> finished
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a tricky design question.

Generally, F# libraries tend to group functions that work with a type (e.g. `list<T>` or `seq<T>`) in a separate module with the name same as the type (e.g. `List.xyz` and `Seq.xyz`). This works well for common types, because the users learn how to find the functions.

However, for less common types (e.g. your own library), it may be a bit difficult to discover these modules (especially if the type is not created explicitly (but is obtained as a result of some call). Having one module name and then use `.` to explore it is quite powerful.

I would probably suggest using nested modules. Something like:

```
module EF =
  // common functions
  module Cascadable = 
    // CascadableNavProperty functions
  module Many = 
    // etc.
```

The users could then find everything by starting with `EF`. They'd write something like:

```
entity
|> EF.hasSeq <@ fun z -> z.Books @>
  |> EF.Many.withRequiredProperty <@ fun z -> z.Author @>
    |> EF.Dependent.hasForeignKey <@ fun z -> z.AuthorId @>
      |> EF.Cascadable.willCascadeOnDelete true
|> finished
```